# Symfony doctrine has one through relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, symfony, doctrine

I want to make a relationship like "has one through" in Laravel.

I have a table called "locked_users" with 2 columns "user_id" and "user_type" related to 2 tables "members" and "customers" with a one-to-one relationship.

For example "locked_users" I would have:

- user_id = 1 and user_type = member
- user_id = 1 and user_type = customer

I tried to have both relationship "Customer" and "Member" in my "LockedUser" entity but it doesn't seem to work:

```
/**
         * @var Customer|null
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Eccube\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="customers", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
        private ?Customer $Customer = null;

/**
         * @var Member|null
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Eccube\Entity\Member", inversedBy="members",cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
        private ?Member $Member = null;
```

I also tried to use Inheritance Mapping which creates an abstract class called "LockedUser" and moves the relationship to 2 subclasses "LockedCustomer" and "LockedMember" but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
    /**
     * LockedUser
     *
     * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
     * @ORM\Table(name="mtb_locked_user",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_type", columns={"user_id", "type"})})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customize\Repository\LockedUserRepository")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields={"Customer", "Member"})
     * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator_type", type="string", length=255)
     */
    class LockedUser extends \Eccube\Entity\AbstractEntity{}
```

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="mtb_locked_user",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_type", columns={"user_id", "type"})})
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorValue(value="locked_customer")
     */
    class LockedCustomer extends LockedUser
    {
        /**
         * @var Customer|null
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Eccube\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="customers")
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
        private ?Customer $Customer = null;
}
```

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="mtb_locked_user",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_type", columns={"user_id", "type"})})
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorValue(value="locked_member")
     */
    class LockedMember extends LockedUser
    {
        /**
         * @var Member|null
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Eccube\Entity\Member", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumns({
         *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         * })
         */
        private ?Member $Member = null;
}
```

When I save an entity. it just only can save one "Customer" or "Member". If one works then the other doesn't. Sometimes both do not work

Comment: Start by fixing your data model. Having typed relationships is often an indicator of a problem. The name of your table `locked_users` suggests that you are locking a user entity but you are trying to lock either a member or a customer. Perhaps you need to model both members and customers as specialisations of user. Then you are locking a user regardless of type.